# Update post meta without deleting the old entries

Tags: forms, post-meta

```
$old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields', true);
$new = array();

$figuresugsubjectpositions = $_POST['figuresugsubjectposition'];
$figuresugsubjectworkplaces = $_POST['figuresugsubjectworkplace'];
$figuresugsubjectlocations = $_POST['figuresugsubjectlocation'];
$figuresugsubjectfroms = $_POST['figuresugsubjectfrom'];
$figuresugsubjectstatuss = $_POST['figuresugsubjectstatus'];


$count = count( $figuresugsubjectpositions );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if ( $figuresugsubjectpositions[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectposition'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $figuresugsubjectpositions[$i] ) );

        $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectworkplace'] = $figuresugsubjectworkplaces[$i];
        $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectlocation'] = $figuresugsubjectlocations[$i];
        $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectfrom'] = $figuresugsubjectfroms[$i];
        $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectstatus'] = $figuresugsubjectstatuss[$i];

    endif;
}

if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields', $new );
elseif ( empty($new) && $old )
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields', $old );
```

I have a frontend form for post submission. I want the new entries in the form not to replace the old ones, instead I want it to be added. I guess the problem is with the update_post_meta thing. I saves the new entries over the old. Is there anyway I keep the old ones and put the new ones with new keys?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields', $new );
```

with:

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields', $new );
```

to add more values related to the `figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields` meta key.

You should also consider using [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Thank you. That's correct but the problem is when add_post_meta, I no longer able to update/ delete existing ones. Any clue?

Comment: I thought you didn't want to delete the existing ones ;-) Are you talking about another edit form?

Comment: It is the same form. Well, yes I don't want to delete the existing ones, but at the same time I want them to be edited and updated. The thing is that I have made the form open to all users for the same post. Every user can come and make edits, but instead of replacing the existing ones, I want them to add/ edit or delete upon their choice. I know it's not entirly clear but I can explain if someone can ask :)

Comment: btw, I have tried array_merge($new, $old) but it's creating duplicates.

Comment: hey @birgire . `update_post_meta` It does exactly the job of adding, and I think the problem is not with this function.

Comment: It is a long time since I wrote this but if I remember correctly that in general we have to be careful with these two functions and their parameters when we have the same meta key stored multiple times with various different meta values under the same post id.